# table display not refresh after delete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi all just want to ask your help on my table display, after i press the delete icon on the row of the table, the row that i pressed to delete still there though on the database it is already deleted. the page wasnt refresh.

this is my table id

```
<div id="display" align="left"></div>
```

this is ajax script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function deletedata(str){

var med_id = str;

$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "deletedata.php?med_id="+med_id,
}).done(function( data ) {


});
}


</script>
```

this is my demo_insert.php

```
<?php

$dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = 'thartpc';
$dbDatabase = 'hospital';
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");


$sql_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages order by med_id desc");


if(isSet($_POST['content2']))

{
$content2=$_POST['content2'];
$content3=$_POST['content3'];
$content4=$_POST['content4'];

mysql_query("insert into messages(medname, quantity, patientid) values  ('$content2','$content3','$content4')");

$sql_in= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages order by med_id desc");
$r=mysql_fetch_array($sql_in);

}

?>


<?php

require_once 'config.php';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages where patientid = '$content4'order by med_id desc") or die ("could not search");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);    

 ?>

    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading"><class="panel-title"><h7>Transaction</h7></div>
            <div class="panel-body" style="padding-top:30px">

                <?php
                    echo "<table class='table table-hover';>
                    <tr>
                    <th style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'> ID</th>
                    <th style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>Patient ID</th>
                    <th style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>Item(s)</th>
                    <th style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>Price</th>
                    <th style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>Quantity</th>
                    <th style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>Amount</th>




                    </tr>";

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 

                    {
                    echo "
                    <tr>
                    <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>".$row['med_id']."</td>
                    <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>".$row['patientid']."</td>
                    <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>".$row['medname']."</td>
                    <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>".$row['quantity']."</td>
                    <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>".$row['quantity']."</td>
                    <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>".$row['quantity']."</td>
                "
                ?>  
                    <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"  onclick="deletedata('<?php echo $row['med_id']; ?>')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
                    </tr> 
                <?php

                    }
                    echo "</table>";    

                ?>  
            </div>
    </div>
```

this is my table delete query

```
<?php
include "getconnect.php";
if(isset($_GET['med_id'])){
$stmt = $conn->prepare("delete from messages where med_id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $med_id);

$med_id = $_GET['med_id'];
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Well where is your code deleting the row in your table?

Comment: well, this is only a small insight on what's happening, can you show us a jsfiddle? My guess is either: remove the element from DOM (js) OR refresh the page

Comment: @Romeo just to point out. there are good libraries like datatables.net which have very advanced functionalities. if your looking for a more comprehensive approach you should have a look at it. Now to your question you can add a row id which is the same as the id your passing to the db

Comment: i updated my post and added my table query

Comment: i added table delete query

Answer (score 0):

if your page not reload then you may delete it manually.

for example think your row id (or something else) is "row123".

the you need to change your code as follow

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function deletedata(str){

var med_id = str;

$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "deletedata.php?med_id="+med_id,
}).done(function( data ) {
  //add this code
  $("#row123").remove();
});
}


</script>
```

Comment: when add this - $("$med_id").remove(); still the same the row wasnt deleted on page display.

Comment: yes you need to add "#" before "$mem_id", if your row id is actually  $mem_id

Comment: because your row id is not $mem_id

Comment: actually the row was deleted on database but on page display still there. there no real time action without refreshing the page

Comment: I added table delete query

Comment: the problem is not your php code. the when you delete row from database, then you must delete html dom element without refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Add Id attribute to the row to be the same as the $row['med_id'] . I have added a data attribute(data-delete) to the row so that we know which id to delete.
You will need to add a class to the button from my code below I have illustrated
what you need to do.

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "
<tr>
    <td id='" . $row['med_id'] . "' style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>" . $row['med_id'] . "</td>
    <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>" . $row['patientid'] . "</td>
    <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>" . $row['medname'] . "</td>
    <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>
    <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>
    <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>
    "
    ?>
    <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'>
        <a class="delete-button btn btn-danger btn-sm"  data-delete="<?php echo $row['med_id']; ?>">
            <span class="glyphicon  glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

On your script do the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//listen to a click even for the button
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.delete-button').click(function () {
            //this will be the id for the data to be deleted on the database
            var med_id = $(this).data('delete');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                url: "deletedata.php?med_id=" + med_id,
                success: function (deletedID) {
                    $("tr#" + deletedID).remove();
                }, error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert("an error occured. delete was not successful :( ");
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Add this to your delete query to return a json valid data which will be the id of the deleted row.

```
<?php
include "getconnect.php";
if (isset($_GET['med_id'])) {
    $med_id = $_GET['med_id'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("delete from messages where med_id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $med_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo json_encode($med_id);
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: my button id is v so when i replace  $( "#v" ).click(function(event), it does not work nor it deleted the item on the database.

Comment: i added table delete query

Comment: something wrong with the ajax code below the line of .remove, brackets color becomes light yellow down to the closing script. it wasnt work

Comment: @Romeo am using a phone try and adapt it. It will work 

Comment: @Romeo this will work. I have simulated the same and its working not

Comment: there's something wrong with the script because the color of the font after .remove line becomes light yellow including the closing script and the rest of the code below it.

Comment: btw - @chapskev i have 3 pages, i placed the database query for table on separate page, which is on demo_insert.php. the delete query is on another page which is deletedata.php. the index page is where i called to display the table query via div id. i tried to place the script on index or on demo_insert still not working.

Comment: @Romeo there was an extra Apostophe on that line i have edited only the script

Comment: @chavskev still not working, when i tried to put the script on the demo_insert.php and when I click the delete button, the alert error poping.

Comment: i tried to separated the delete script on the page and on the database and its working

Comment: this is the script to delete td - <script type="text/javascript">

       
    $('td > a').click(function(){
    var med_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
 
 $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    });
  

</script>

Comment: this is the script to delete data on the database - <script type="text/javascript">

   function deletedata(str){

   var med_id = str;

   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "deletedata.php?med_id="+med_id,
   }).done(function( data ) {
     //add this code
     
   });
   }

  </script>

Comment: that two scripts works but pls help me check if that will work permanently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91167/discussion-between-chapskev-and-romeo).

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo '<tr>
        <td>....</td>
        <td><a class="btn" data-id="'.$row['med_id'].'" /></td>
        </tr>';
}

$('td > a.btn').click(function(){
    var med_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
       ....
    });
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: do i need to delete this - function deletedata(str){ var med_id = str; or insert after this with your $('td > a.btn').click(function(){
    var med_id = $(this).attr('data-id');?

Comment: yeah it no need anymore

Comment: yes, it deleted on the database but not on the page. you just reverse my concern, hehehe it should be both, database and on page

Comment: btw, I also transfer the script code, below the database query same with your post. before the script is on the index page.

Comment: replace `<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"  onclick="deletedata('<?php echo $row['med_id']; ?>')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>` with `<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"  data-id="'<?php echo $row['med_id']; ?>'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>` and use `$('body').delegate('td > a.btn', 'click', function(){ var med_id = ...});` if you want place it on index.

Comment: this doesnt work also - <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-id="'<?php echo $row['med_id']; ?>'">, it does not delete on the database, only on the page.   place below the table query and place on the body it does not delete both.

Comment: show me your new jQuery code and Php delete id from database.

Comment: <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' align='center'><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-id="'<?php echo $row['med_id']; ?>'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>      </tr> <?php } echo "</table>"; ?>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">     
    $('td > a.btn').click(function(){
    var med_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "deletedata.php?med_id="+med_id,
 }).done(function( data ) { });
 $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    });
  

</script>

Comment: Im free now you can add me on skype: nhattuanbl (from viet nam)

Comment: it works now, but i put this - but I add this onclick="deletedata('<?php echo $row['med_id']; ?>')">, with your data-id="'<?php echo $row['med_id']; ?>'"

Comment: but I separate the script for the datbase delete and row delete on page

Answer (score -1):

Just add this after you are done processing. Try and put it in your done function

```
location.reload();
```

Comment: when I add this - location.reload(); - it refresh the page but loses my table display on page. actually when I load the page there is no table display yet, it will display after a button click.

Comment: i added table delete query

Comment: Is there any difference?